# Использование события oninput на один элемент два раза

Tags: javascript, html, события, frontend

Как к одному элементу применить одинаковое событие два раза, но используя разные обращения

```js
const RANGE = document.querySelector('.range');
RANGE.oninput = () => {
    line.style.width = RANGE.value;
}    
num.oninput = () => {
    p.innerHTML = num.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="num" class="range" style="margin: 0">
<p id="p"></p>
<div id="line" style="width:0px; height:5px; background-color: #000"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const RANGE = document.querySelector('.range');
RANGE.addEventListener("input", () => {
  line.style.width = RANGE.value + "px";
});
num.addEventListener("input", () => {
  p.innerHTML = num.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="num" class="range" style="margin: 0">
<p id="p">Test</p>
<div id="line" style="width:0px; height:5px; background-color: #000"></div>
```